# Creating a chart using information from a datagridview in c#

Tags: c#, charts, datagridview, textbox

I have two text boxes that divide two numbers, and the answer of the two numbers gets converted into a percentage. The answer is inserted into a datagridview with 12 columns. I want to create a line graph using data entered from a datagridview.

I have inserted a chart into the application, the one found in the toolbox.

```
private void LineGraph_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Series myseries = new Series();
    Series.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;

    chartArea chartArea1 = new ChartArea();
    chartArea1.AxisX.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
    chartArea1.AxisY.MajorGrid.LineColor = Color.LightGray;
    chartArea1.AxisX.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
    chartArea1.AxisY.LabelStyle.Font = new Font("Consolas", 8);
    LineGraph.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea1);

    LineGraph.Series.Add(myseries);

    LineGraph.Series[0].XValueMember = dataGridView1.Columns[0].DataPropertyName;
    LineGraph.Series[0].YValueMembers = dataGridView1.Columns[1].DataPropertyName;
    LineGraph.DataSource = dataGridView1.DataSource;
    LineGraph.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    LineGraph.SaveImage("chart.png", ChartImageFormat.Png);

    chartArea1.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Months; chartArea1.AxisX.Interval = 1;
    chartArea1.Series.Add(myseries);
    chartArea1.Series["Series"].BorderWidth = 500;
    chartArea1.Series["Series"].Points.DataBindXY(table.DefaultView, DGV.Columns[0].Name, table.DefaultView, DGV.Columns[16].Name);
}

private void Calculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string combo = comboBoxMachine.Text;
    int a = Convert.ToInt32(Total_Pass.Text);
    int b = Convert.ToInt32(TotalParts.Text);           
    int p = (a * 100)/b;
    int x = comboBoxMachine.SelectedIndex;

    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[1].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[2].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[3].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[5].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[6].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[7].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[8].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[9].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[10].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[11].Value = p.ToString();
    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[12].Value = p.ToString();

    dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[0].Value = combo;

    if (p<=100)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[9].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[10].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[11].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[12].Style.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
    if (p<=94)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[9].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[10].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[11].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[12].Style.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
    }
    if (p<91)
    {
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[1].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[2].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[3].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[4].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[5].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[6].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[7].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[8].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[9].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[10].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[11].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
        dataGridView2.Rows[x].Cells[12].Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
    dataGridView2.Rows.Add();
}
```

When using the code I get the following error CS0246.

> The type or namespace name 'chartArea' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: `chartArea` should be replaced with `ChartArea` in `LineGraph_Click`

Comment: Also: You really should get into the habit of creating short references instead of repeating all those array accesses! (`DataGridViewRow row = dataGridView2.Rows[x]` etc)

Comment: Thank you for that information!

Comment: Error CS0111 Type 'Resources_Table' already defines a member called 'Calculate_Click' with the same parameter types 
Error CS0121 The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'Resources_Table.Calculate_Click(object, EventArgs)' and 'Resources_Table.Calculate_Click(object, EventArgs)' 
Error CS0117 'Series' does not contain a definition for 'Series' 
Error CS1061 'ChartArea' does not contain a definition for 'Series' and no accessible extension method 'Series' accepting a first argument of type 'ChartArea' could be found.

Comment: Error CS1061 'ChartArea' does not contain a definition for 'Series' and no accessible extension method 'Series' accepting a first argument of type 'ChartArea' could be found